# How to useRef and scrollIntoView to scroll to specific element in a mapped list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of events that is scrollable on the y axis, as below:

```
 {events.map((event) => (
   <li
     ref={event.ref}
     key={event.id}
     >
     {event.name)
   </li>
 ))}
```

When clicking a button I would like the event I specify to scroll to the top of the above mapped list.

I am currently using useRef, but I am unsure how to specify the exact event I would like to scroll to the top.

For example, let's say I would like to scroll to the event with an id of 5, when clicking the button.

Here is my current code:

```
 const eventRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollToMyRef = () =>
    eventRef.current.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "end",
      inline: "nearest",
    });

   <button
     onClick={() => scrollToMyRef()}
    >
      Click me
   </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep track of which `event.id` you want to scroll to in state, and then only render a `ref` on the event that matches the `id` in state.

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-sea-hujjni?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState('1');

  const ref = useRef(null);

  const handleButtonClick = () =>
    ref.current.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start',
      inline: 'nearest',
    });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click me</button>
      {events.map((event) => (
        <li ref={event.id === id ? ref : null} key={event.id}>
          {event.name})
        </li>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! How would I pass A specific event.id on click? For example if I wanted to pass event.id 5?

Comment: You can initialize useState with the id 5, `const [id, setId] = useState(5);` Or call `setId(5)` in an event callback. What event would you like to use to update the id? Maybe a button click? Or form input?

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I just had a go with the sandbox and saw how you have implemented it there. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @adherb you can change the `block` argument in `scrollIntoView` to `block: 'start'` instead of `end`. I have updated the answer and the code sandbox.

Comment: I was getting an error when I would select values that didn't match the event.id, to fix this I added If (!ref.current) {  return
    } else {  ref.current.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start',
      inline: 'nearest',
    });}. I can't update the answer as the suggested edit queue is full.

Comment: I also had to move it to a useEffect function adding id to the dependencies array.